# roscpp message callback threading?

Tags: ros, subscribe, roscpp, callbacks

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If a simple node with ros::spin() in the main loop subscribes to two messages, will the message callbacks be called sequentially or be potentially processed in parallel?

Is the GlobalCallbackQueue global to all nodes/ROS, or just the node making the call?

I reviewed [roscpp/Overview/Callbacks](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscpp/Overview/Callbacks%20and%20Spinning), and it indicates that there is a callback queue(s), but it doesn't confirm that one callback completes before the next callback is initiated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9755/roscpp-message-callback-threading?/) by [Bart](https://answers.ros.org/users/286/bart/) on ROS Answers with karma: 856 on 2011-04-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

All threading is local to processes.

All callbacks can be associated with a specific callback queue.   All callbacks go into the default queue if not specified.  A NodeHandle can have a custom callback queue associated with it, or specific callback registrations.

If you have a single thread servicing a callback queue.  All will be serial.

Any specific callback will only be called after the last instance has finished, regardless of how many threads there are in the queue.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-04-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3